# How to extract user ID in between a text of varied length in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have to target ONLY the user ID from the middle of a text with varied length. If it's possible at all.

**Scenario:**

Here are 3 different information that I have in `A2, B2, and C2`

```
**A2** |  *BZ_PH0102~grahambenjamin.NBSC_BookDelivery_Print.09-01.22:42:06*    
**B2** |  *AS_P24~greenerobert.NBSC_BookDelivery_Print.09-01.23:32:43*    
**C2** |  *AS_P16~chernowron.NBSC_BookDelivery_Print.09-02.02:22:51*
```

I need to extract the different user IDs after the **~** and enter them in `column D`

For the sample above, it would be: *grahambenjamin*, *greenerobert*, and *chernowron*.

It would have been easy if the length is not too varied. Right now I'm only using `=MID(A2,FIND("~",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-41-FIND("~",A2)-1)` in `D2`.

The formula works ,but isn't completely correct. I just tried to experiment with it but I couldn't get the right one.

I also tried `=LEFT(A4, SEARCH(".",A4)-1)`

But only extract data left of **.**

Finally, I tried to add a right delimit, but it's not working properly as well.

`=RIGHT(A3,SEARCH("~",A3))&LEFT(A3, SEARCH(".",A3)-1)`

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes sir! That's right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want everything **between** the **first** `~` and the **first** `.` then...

---

```
=MID(A22,FIND("~",A22)+1,FIND(".",A22)-FIND("~",A22)-1)
```

---

### Explanation

> `MID( String , Starting Position , Number of Characters )`

You already figured out how to find the starting point. Now we want to know how many characters to count to the right from that starting point.

Mathematically this would be the position of the period MINUS the position of the ~ and then MINUS 1 to offset the period. That calculation gives you the actual length of your string which we want to extract. So we are saying start at this position and count x many characters to the right.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Can you please tell me though, what the formula means so I can reuse it when I need it. I only understand that it will look for ~ as the starting point and then a period as the end. What does ```-FIND``` supposed to do?

Comment: @AldrinRenzCruz Although not relevant based on your current examples, if the text before the first `~` contains a `.` (e.g. `*PI_3.14~urdearboy.NBSC_BookDelivery_Print.10-05.12:34:56*`), then you may get an error (Because you are asking for a negative number of characters).  In which case, you need to `FIND` the first `.` *after* the first `~`, or `FIND(".",A22,FIND("~",A22))`

Comment: Yea, the usage of `first` in my answer is very important :) @Chronocidal. At that point VBA becomes ideal. Dynamically doing that in equation would be lengthy I imagine